# How to override filenames via file description field in uploaded files?

Tags: entities, files

I'm using [File (Field) Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) to change filenames of uploaded files. There's a nice option to enable file description. I want the files to be renamed according to that file description (I tried to find a replacement pattern for this; there does not seem to be one). In terms of doing so the file description field should be a required field, which is not allowed to be empty.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: You've already mention 2 parts you need to solve: you need a token that supports the file's description field & you need that field to be required. The token API gets you the first, `hook_form_alter()` in a custom module can get you the 2nd.